# Mac OS: zero-byte files in home directory

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have some strange empty (zero-byte) files in my home directory and I have no idea from where they come. 
I installed 'brew' on fresh Mac OS Mojave around this time.
There are many 'version like' empty files with no content.
Additionally, there are files called `The`, `This` and `Homebrew`.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.2.1
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.2.2
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.2.3
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.2.4
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.2.5
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.2.6
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.0
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.1
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.2
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.3
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.4
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.5
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.6
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.7
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.8
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.3.9
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.4.0
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.4.1
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.4.2
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.4.3
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.5.0
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.5.1
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.5.10
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.5.11
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.5.12
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.11
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.12
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.13
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.14
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.15
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.16
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.17
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.2
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.3
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.4
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.5
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.6
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.7
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.8
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.6.9
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.7.0
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.7.1
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.7.2
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.7.3
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.7.4
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.7.5
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 1.7.6
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 Homebrew
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 The
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff      0 Jan 31 00:11 This
```

Command `file ./The` return `empty`.

Where they come from ?

Comment: How exactly did you install homebrew?

Comment: I followed this installation procedure:  https://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Homebrew/